# How can we associate this process to one record? (Record Id in Controller, Prepopulate Field A and prompt user input for Field B.)

Tags: visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

Really looking for some help/insights here..Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Here's my scenario:

A record id can be obtained in the controller using ApexPages.currentpage().getParameters().get('RecId') when 'RecId' is already parsed in the URL...

The problem is:
Say a record with id=RecId already exists with values in Field A. Now, we need to prompt user to enter data in Field B and also show them value of Field A by autopopulating..

I am having extremely difficult time to figure out how to tie up both the prepopulate and update process to the same record.

If I use ApexPages.StandardController.getRecord, it would allow me update the Field B. But how can I prepopulate field B. Or vice versa..how to do both at the same time?

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: What do you want to? Is it an existing or a new record? Are you editing and saving it? Why do you need a visualforce page and controller for that?

Comment: here's my scenario:
- An existing record with name REC14 in the custom object FIFA__c with value 'Brazil' in the fields Venue__c and empty field Comments__c 
- Prompting non SFDC users provide Comments_c via Sites Page.
- In that page a disabled inputText inside outputPanel will already be prepopulated with the value of Venue__c of the record REC 14
- Users will provide texts in another inputField which will be stored in Comments__c of the existing record REC 14.